# Workflow Manager config doesn't recognize open ports

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, workflow-manager

Good afternoon, all!

I'm trying to get Workflow Manager installed so I can do some dev.  The Configuration for Service Bus section of the Config Wizard has a problem seeing the open ports on the firewall for HTTPS port 9355 and Internal Communication Port Range 9000-9004.  These ports are specifically open in Windows Firewall.  I also tried setting this up with the "Enable firewall rules on this computer" tick boxes unchecked.  The Summary page shows the value FALSE, but I still get "port 9355 is blocked" and "port 9002 is blocked" . Netstat shows the ports in listening mode.

The installation string said it finished successfully, but I have some errors in the Application logs referring to the Service Bus Message Broker.  Apparently it crashed, but I restarted both the Message Broker and the Service Bus Gateway.  Don't know if these are significant, but it deserved mentioning.

Thanks to all for looking!

Gregg

Comment: You say the ports are in a listening state. Can you validate that it is WFM/SB processes listening on those ports? Obviously you cannot re-use a port for another application, which is what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 0):

OK - got this finally.
Found and installed a CU for Service Bus, rebooted server and logged in as the SP Administrator, not the domain admin.  Ran the configurator and it's done.

Next problem - unhandled exception in Workflow Service Host.